# Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state

Tags: node.js, express, mysql2

I have recently deployed my node.js API application on live server. I am getting these issue on live server.

I have googled it, but could not get any exact solution. Can anyone suggest how can i solve this problem?

```
{ Error: read ETIMEDOUT at TCP.onread (net.js:622:25) errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', code: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read', fatal: true }

 { Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state at PoolConnection._addCommandClosedState }
```

I amd using the mysql connection pool like this

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var mysqlPool = mysql.createPool({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: 'xyz',
database: 'xyz',
waitForConnections: true,
connectionLimit: 10,
queueLimit: 0
});
module.exports = mysqlPool;
```

Comment: We need more code. How are you querying the database? Which line of your code throws the error?

Comment: do you have mysql running in the `localhost` in respect to your where Node.js application resides on?

Comment: ETIMEDOUT usually happens when server is not running or because of a firewall problem (or any network accessibility problem)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended up having to put the connection request in it's own .js file and import it into the controller-
**connectionRequest.js**

```
module.exports = function () {

    let mysql = require('mysql2')
    let connCreds = require('./connectionsConfig.json');

    //Establish Connection to the DB
    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: connCreds["host"],
        user: connCreds['username'],
        password: connCreds['password'],
        database: connCreds['database'],
        port: 3306
    });

    //Instantiate the connection
    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`connectionRequest Failed ${err.stack}`)
        } else {
            console.log(`DB connectionRequest Successful ${connection.threadId}`)
        }
    });

    //return connection object
    return connection
}
```

Once I did that I was able to import it into my query on the controller file like so
**ControllerFile.js**

```
let connectionRequest = require('../config/connectionRequest')

controllerMethod: (req, res, next) => {
    //Establish the connection on this request
    connection = connectionRequest()

    //Run the query
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM table", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) {
            // If an error occurred, send a generic server failure
            console.log(`not successful! ${err}`)
            connection.destroy();

        } else {
            //If successful, inform as such
            console.log(`Query was successful, ${result}`)

            //send json file to end user if using an API
            res.json(result)

            //destroy the connection thread
            connection.destroy();
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of messing around I was able to solve the problem by destroying the connection, waiting (this is the important page) and getting the connection again.

```
conn = await connPool.getConnection();
// We have error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
// I'm attempting to solve it by grabbing a new connection
if (!conn || !conn.connection || conn.connection._closing) {
  winston.info('Connection is in a closed state, getting a new connection');
  await conn.destroy(); // Toast that guy right now
  sleep.sleep(1); // Wait for the connection to be destroyed and try to get a new one, you must wait! otherwise u get the same connection
  conn = await connPool.connection.getConnection(); // get a new one
}
```